# How do I get the nav bar to be next to companytm and the search bar to be next to it to the right?

Tags: html, css, fixed, navbar

was just needing help on getting the search bar up inline with the nav bar but to the right and putting the navbar next to the text companytm???
Pllllzzzzzz help

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/99D6a/

```
<>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/99D6a/2/) should work.

I moved the search form to beside the company text and added this style.

```
#tfnewsearch
{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 6px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    float: right;
}
```